# How do I set a variable equal to the top of the stack? C#

Tags: c#

I have a stack of ints, and I'm trying to set a new int equal to the value at the top of the stack. I've tried setting the new int equal to Stack.Pop() and Stack.Peek(), but keep getting an error stating that an object can't be set to an int.

```
public static int IntFound(ref Stack valStack)
{
   val = 0;
   if (valStack.Count > 0)
     int val = valStack.Pop();
   return val;
}
```

Comment: You could do ` val = Convert.ToInt32(valStack.Pop());` . However, one question, why have you passed the parameter as ref ?

Comment: you are returning `int` value but in your function you mentioned the object value. There is no way to pass `int` to an `object`

Comment: two additional thoughts: there's no need for `Stack` to be by-ref here (unless this is a custom `struct` of yours); and - IMO you should *throw* if the stack is empty - that's an underflow

Comment: Not answering your question, but you are assigning val = 0; then defining  int val = valStack.Pop(), does that even compile?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a non-generic version of Stack, then you could do the following.

```
public static int IntFound(Stack valStack)
{
    var val = 0;
    if (valStack.Count > 0)
        val = Convert.ToInt32(valStack.Peek());
    return val;
}
```

Please note that you do not need to pass the stack with the `ref` if you do not intend to alter the caller's variable. The non-generic version of Stack stores values as an object. You would hence need to use `Convert.ToInt32()` to convert an object to int.

Alternatively, you could also use the generic version of Stack (`Stack<int>`)

```
public static int IntFound(Stack<int> valStack)
{
    var val = 0;
    if (valStack.Count > 0)
       val = valStack.Peek();
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some other reason, it is not compiling in my machine, just updated the code window snippet in the question, please have a look and remove the image after use

Comment: possibly was missing System.Collection namespace